# Weird behavior with the variable data

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have following code

```
    <div class="gameContainer">
      <span
        v-for="(tile, index) in shuffledTiles"
        :key="`${tile}_${index}`"
        :data-key="`${tile}_${index}`"
        :class="['tile-data px-2', tile, getClass(tile + index, tile)]"
        @click="clickHandler(tile + index, tile)"
      >
        <img :src="`icons/${tile}.svg`" :alt="tile" />
      </span>
    </div>
```

When the above code is rendered, img src and alt values are completely different. I tried console.log inside `shuffledTiles` and got values in browser console. one by `Nuxt SSR` and one from my code. both are completely different order.

If you look at the dom tree, data-key is different and image src is different.

you can see the code here https://github.com/stefanre1/game/blob/master/components/Game.vue

I am not sure whats going on. any hint would be helpful. This is my first project.

[image]

Comment: When you say they are 'different', do you mean that the attributes are inconsistent with each other, or just that the server-side and client-side values differ? The code for `shuffledTiles` is randomly shuffling using `Math.random` so it'll give a different ordering each time it's called.

Comment: @skirtle Please see the screenshot. img src should be apple but its tomato.

Comment: @skirtle `shuffledTiles` will give different results for sure but only when refreshed. but as soon the page is visible, it already messes up. :-|

Comment: you cant use random for results that will be server rendered and then client rehydrated. you code should produce same result in client and server or be just executed on client only e.g. inside mounted hook

Comment: @Aldarund Thank you. That solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are shuffling tiles twice. Once during SSR and one on the client side.

Do it only once. An easy solution can be to render the game component only on the client side by wrapping it up in [client-only](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/) component

```
<client-only>
  <game>
</client-only>
```

Or, may be better one is to create a prop for the game component, called `tiles`. And, compute that within [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/api/#the-asyncdata-method) hook of the index page. And pass that as prop to game component.

In your `index.vue`, you add

```
data: () => ({
  tiles: null
}),
asyncData() {
  const tilesData = [
    'apple',
    'orange',
    'tomato',
    'strawberry',
    'tree',
    'lemon'
  ]

  const tiles = [...tilesData, ...tilesData]

  for (let i = tiles.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
    ;[tiles[i], tiles[j]] = [tiles[j], tiles[i]]
  }

  return { tiles }
}
```

And, pass that as prop to game component

```
<game :tiles="tiles" />
```

And, in your game.vue component, you define `tiles` as prop and use it.

```
props: {
  tiles: {
    type: Array,
    required: true
  }
},
```

Loop over `tiles` instead of `shuffledTiles`

```
<span
  v-for="(tile, index) in tiles"
  :key="`${tile}_${index}`"
  :data-key="`${tile}_${index}`"
  :class="['tile-data px-2', tile, getClass(tile + index, tile)]"
  @click="clickHandler(tile + index, tile)"
>
  <img :src="`icons/${tile}.svg`" :alt="tile" />
</span>
```

The reason this works is because, `asyncData` is executed only on the server side when the page loads. And whatever is returned from the asyncData is merged into the data of the page component. And, passed along to the browser. So when on the browser, the app is constructed again, it uses the same data instead of constructing a new one.

PS. Seems like a fun game. Good luck finishing it. :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer :-) I used `<client-only>`. Ans thanks for the encouragement. Even though its a basic game, it works fine now :-) https://musing-ramanujan-d17c9d.netlify.com/